# evaluation of triple Integration enclosed betwen $2$ parabolid.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Evaluation of Integration of $\displaystyle\iiint z\,dV$ over the regin between two parabolid $z=x^2+y^2$ and $z=2-x^2-y^2.$

What i try

Solve $z=x^2+y^2=2-x^2-y^2\Longrightarrow x^2+y^2=2$

It represent an circle whose center is $(0,0)$ and radius is $\sqrt{2}.$ and here $y=\sqrt{2-x^2}.$

So integration is $$\int^{\sqrt{2}}_{0}\int^{\sqrt{2-x^2}}_{0}\int^{2-x^2-y^2}_{x^2+y^2}zdxdydx$$

Can you please tell me what i have done is right or we multiply by a factor of $4$ in this integration.

Could some help me to solve it. Thanks

Comment: Why not use cylindrical shells? Otherwise yes, you multiply by 4, or extend the lower limit for the first two integrals, first from $-\sqrt 2$, and the second from $-\sqrt{2-x^2}$

Comment: Means in my original intehral we have to multiply it by a factor of $4$.

Comment: it should be a circle of radius $1$. $x^2+y^2 = 2 - x^2 - y^2$ implies $x^2 + y^2 = 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So your idea is correct, but your limits are wrong. As noted, the intersection is a circle of radius $\sqrt{2}$, but in your limits you have defined a quarter circle of the same radius and hence you need to multiply by a factor of 4. A simpler method would be as suggested by @Andrei, where we take a cylindrical polar system so $\rho = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$, and polar angle $\phi$. Then the integral becomes $\int_0^{\sqrt{2}} \int _{0}^{2\pi} \int _{\rho^2} ^{2-\rho^2} \rho dz d\phi d\rho $.